# How to wrap ionic-card with fixed size?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, sass, material-design

I've a bunch of `ionic-card`(I guess the kind of element isn't relevant) to display.

I initially tried to display them in an `ion-grid`:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col  *ngFor="let trip of trips$ | async" size-lg="3" size="6" size-sm="12"> 
            <ion-card class="trip" class="ion-no-padding" [routerLink]="[trip.id]">
              <img [src]="trip?.coverImageUrl ? trip.coverImageUrl: '/assets/img/defaultImage.jpg'" style="width: 100%" />
              <ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-title>{{trip.name}}</ion-card-title>
                <ion-card-subtitle>{{trip.startDate.toDate() | date}}</ion-card-subtitle>
              </ion-card-header>
            </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

but when I'm resizing the image, the size of each cards varies until I hit the breakpoint. In my case, I would like to have the elements being exactly 150px width and fits as much as possible on one line.

By example, if somebody comes with an ultra-wide monitor, I don't want to have only 12 elements in the width that are stretched.

How to achieves this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to have the elements being exactly 150px width and fits as much as possible on one line.
> By example, if somebody comes with an ultra-wide monitor, I don't want to have only 12 elements in the width that are stretched

Not exactly related to Ionic but you can achieve that using [CSS Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for example.

Please take a look at this **[working Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66275519?file=src/app/pages/home/home.page.ts)**.

[image: Grid CSS demo]

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
    <div class="grid">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="grid-item">
            {{ item }}
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.grid-item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

This can be done in a lot of different ways but if you're curious to learn more about CSS Grid Layout, I'd recommend taking a look at the *Guides* section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout#guides

Comment: I like the approach. I will investigate on it, thanks!